# Jquery Tabs and Uploadify Object Expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin inside jquery tabs which works perfectly fine. Inside the uploadify once upload is completed i am sending email as such :

```
 $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileTypeExts': '*.gif; *.jpg',
                'swf': 'Scripts/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': 'FileUploadHandler.ashx',
                'cancelImg': 'Scripts/Uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Browse',
                'onQueueComplete': function (queueData) {
                senEmail();
                }
            });
```

My `sendEmail` function is in `Ready function` of the page as below:

```
var senEmail = function() {
                var notes = $("#<%=txtMessage.UniqueID%>");

                var msgbox = $("#cerror");
                $("#cerror").hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ContactMe.aspx/SendEmail",
                    data: "{'message': '" + notes.val() + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d == 'Sent') {
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs(); // declare the tabs
            $tabs.tabs("url", 5, "/ContactConfirmation.aspx"); // change the URL of the selected tab
            $tabs.tabs("select", 5 + 1); // refresh the tab content
alert("masTEST3");
            $tabs.tabs("select", 5 ); // refresh the tab content
alert("endTEST");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#cerror").show();
                            msgbox.html(msg.d);
                        }
                    }

                });
            };
```

Now the above works fine as in sends an email, but when I am forwarding the user to confirmation page, I get the jquery error : `Object Expected` and does not forward to next page on same tab(this works on other pages).

appreciate your help.

***EDIT:::***

here is the IE9 error :

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 24275
```

and the debugger is on this line:

```
return!t||t!==!0&&e.getAttribute("classid")===t}})
```

Comment: **Where** do you get the error (on which of the lines above)? Have you walked through the code in the debugger built into your browser? If so, what have you found out? (If not, why not? ;-) )

Comment: if I put alerts() I can see alert("endTEST"); it is opening the jquery min file on error

Comment: and this only happens in IE9 works find on chrome and firefox

Comment: @ Sam1: Don't use `alerts` for debugging, use a debugger for debugging. If the problem is occurring on IE9, open your page in IE9 and press F12. That will open IE9's debugger, with which you can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my edit please, it shows that error

Comment: @ Sam1: Which line of **your code** is the error occurring on? E.g., what line of your code calling jQuery causes jQuery to throw this error?

Comment: You try to make the redirect on code behind ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it doesn't show anything on my code, how do I check it? If i comment out the part where I forward to next page I don't get the error

Comment: more tests :: if i comment out this line $tabs.tabs("select", 5 ); I dont get the error but it doesnt forward to confirmation page

Comment: @ Sam1: Again, stop trying to debug by commenting things out, doing alerts, etc. **Walk through with the debugger**, single-stepping your code. That will tell you exactly what's going on. Good luck with it,

Comment: @Aristos i tried it using HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/ContactConfirmation.aspx"); as my method will be static still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in case someone else has same problem:

I had to destroy the uploadify object when the tab was changing/reloading so all I had to do was before sending email include this line :

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify("destroy");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem after a fashion.

Calling

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify("destroy");
```

after `onUploadComplete` does work. But if you click on anything else without uploading a file it would crash all javascript on my project. So I started using

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify("destroy");
```

in several places which caused this new error to arise (something about settings having a `null` or `undefined` object). I figure its because I'm trying to call destroy when I'm not able to. Either way that way wasn't working either.

So I opened up `uploadify.js` and decided to disable some of these options while uploadify is running destroy.

Find the `destroy function` in uploadify.js and comment this out

```
    var $this        = $(this),
    swfuploadify = $this.data('uploadify');
    //settings     = swfuploadify.settings;
```

now uncomment anything below `this` that is using `settings` like:

```
/*/ 
    // Destroy the queue
    if (settings.defaultQueue) {
        $('#' + settings.queueID).remove();
    }

    // Reload the original DOM element
    $('#' + settings.id).replaceWith(swfuploadify.original);

    // Call the user-defined event handler
    if (settings.onDestroy) settings.onDestroy.call(this);
/*/
```

This will work. And you can still upload pictures and everything. The only down fall is that you lose the options of what these items do. In my situation I'm just uploading one picture at a time so this works for me. You do still have to use

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify("destroy");
```

before you run any other javascript with in that `div`. So any tabs or buttons you have other than the uploadify button, you need to have them destroy uploadify when you push those buttons. It has to be the very first action after a click.